# Problem in using htaccess file to control single php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

on my website, to search and compare prices of different things, I've form having 'search' button. When user enter keyword(thing for which he want to compare price), category etc. and click 'search' button, URL in address bar is exactly the same that i want (i.e /sp/searchresults/camera/115/Search/bla/bla/////) using following code:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^searchresults(.*)$
>
> searchresults.php?keyword=$1&categories=$2&t=$3&btnsearch=$4&manuf=$5&brname=$6&pricerange=$7&h=$8&k=$9&merchantid=$10&sort=$11
>   [L]

Now the problem is when i want to have that 'keyword','merchantid' and 'sort'  on any other page, it gives me '.php' instead of giving me item name,merchant id and sort result.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea your problem is a few,

For starters with ^searchresults(.*)$ you will only get $1 no others as you saying capture everything after searchresults as one (),

The second i'm not sure about is that your have got $11 i'm sure your only allowed 10 but will have to wait for another user to say if that is the case.

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^searchresults_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)$ searchresults.php?keyword=$1&categories=$2&t=$3&btnsearch=$4&manuf=$5&brname=$6&pricerange=$7&h=$8&k=$9&merchantid=$10&sort=$11 [L]
```

But still not sure it will work as you have more than 10 $vars

For Comment
RewriteRule ^serachresults(.*?)$ search.php [L]

P.S i found another problem your ^searchresults(.*)$ would have acted on the searchresults.php and created a redirect loop

Comment: I'm Sorry then i cant help then i think your sending far to much info though your Rewrite the best thing you can do is send it all to a php scrip then get php to parse the filename for your vars

Comment: i've tried following code and its working now            RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?).searchresults$ 

searchresults.php?keyword=$1&categories=$2&t=$3&btnsearch=$4&manuf=$5&brname=$6&pricerange=$7&h=$8&k=$9&merchantid=$

10&sort=$11 [L]

Comment: hrm wounder why it did not work with the underscores then, but if you have it working then glad i could help a little :p

Comment: Have another problem,when i don't specify 'keyword' and left all fields blank and click on 'search' button, it gives me this error :    You don't have permission to access /sp/ /0/Search/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/searchresults on this server.

Comment: i would post that as another question, as that looks like an apache error if your getting access error like that but you might need to google /0 you might ave just found a hack to get to the root of a system so if some retard has apache running as a root there is a big problem, so i would look around a bit then ask you question but why is your pages sending a user to /0/0 it should be sending them to //Search///////searchresults

Comment: because I've applied condition that if these fields are empty,place '0' there.. Like this:  <input type="hidden" id="pricerange" name="pricerange" value="<?php echo $pricerange!=""?$pricerange:0; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule
>   ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?).searchresults$
>
> searchresults.php?keyword=$1&categories=$2&t=$3&btnsearch=$4&manuf=$5&brname=$6&pricerange=$7&h=$8&k=$9&merchantid=$10&sort=$11 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I would have is to use a HTACCESS rule like the following:

```
RewriteRule searchresult/(.*)$ searchresults.php?fullparam=$1
```

Then, within your PHP Script, parse the `$_GET['fullparam']` value.

```
$params = array();
if( isset( $_GET['fullparam'] ) )
  $params = explode( '/' , $_GET['fullparam'] );
  # You can use any delimiter, '/' or '_' or '-' or whatever you like
```

OR, using the Parameter Order and Names mentioned in the Original Question

```
if( isset( $_GET['fullparam'] ) )
  list( $keyword , $categories , $t , $btnsearch , $manuf , $brname ,
        $pricerange , $h , $k , $merchantid , $sort ,  )
    = explode( '/' , $_GET['fullparam'] , 12 );
```

The benefit of this solution is that you have the simplest possible HTACCESS rule, and you can use the flexibility of PHP to allow for any number of elements in your URLs.

Comment: Welcome - happy to do so. Have you tried it? Did it work? Did one of the other Answers help you? If so, help us (and any other viewers of this answer) out by letting us know. Vote up (click the up arrow) beside any votes which helps, and mark any Answer (one per question) which solved the problem as correct (click the Checkmark below the arrows). Cheers!

Comment: well my problem was resolved before your post : ) .. Barkermn01's answer helped rectifying my issue so voting for him..